# Por que @import não ta funcionando corretamente?

Tags: css, css3, importação

Estou tentando importar um CSS, dentro de outro mas não está funcionando, a estrutura do diretório está assim:

style.css
css/agoravou.css

Porém não está funcionando o comando `@import url('css/agoravou.css') screen;`.
Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: O @importe tem que ser a primeira coisa do seu arquivo CSS, se não, não funciona. Ele é a primeira cosia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `@import` precisa estar na primeira linha do arquivo.

Mas também pode ser algum problema com as permissões da pasta `css`.

Answer (score -3):

isso pode ter varios motivos entao precisaria do seu codigo para solucionar. Como ja disseram o @import tem que estar na primeira linha do seu arquivo. Entretanto se voce estiver usando um framework como o bootstrap por exemplo, e voce quer customizar alguma coisa que ja nao vem pronta no frame, voce precisa colocar o seu link do css depois do link do boostrap, senao ele nao vai se sobrepor, tendo em vista que a leitura do codigo pelo navegador se da de cima para baixo